# Multiple Functions using Functional Bean Definition in Spring Cloud for AWS Lambda

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-function

I am trying to create a Spring Cloud Function application which will have multiple functions defined in it. I need to use the Functional Bean definition approach for reduced cold start time. The jar will be deployed in AWS Lambda.

The code works in local environment and I am able to curl for all the functions defined. However when deployed in Lambda , the function is not getting located by AWS.

The code runs and is working as expected on Lambda ,if there is only 1 function defined.

I will mention below the things that I have tried.

1. Followed the  [Spring Doc](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-function/2.0.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__functional_bean_definitions.html) to create the project
2. This works fine in local and also runs in Lambda with Handler `org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootStreamHandler::handleRequest`
   as per the comment by Thannasi on [mydeveloperplanet blog post](https://mydeveloperplanet.com/2020/11/04/how-to-deploy-a-spring-cloud-function-on-aws-lambda/)
3. Next I added few more functions and registered them with the Generic ApplicationContext

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class Multi_FunctionalBean1Application implements ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> {
            
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    FunctionalSpringApplication.run(Multi_FunctionalBean1Application.class, args);
                }
            
                public Function<String, Boolean> containsCloud() {
                    return value -> {
                        System.out.println("Value is " + value);
                        return value.contains("cloud");
                    };
                }
            
                public Function<String, String> lowercase() {
                    return String::toLowerCase;
                }
            
                public Function<String, String> uppercase() {
                    return String::toUpperCase;
                }
            
                @Override
                public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext context) {
                    context.registerBean("containsCloud", FunctionRegistration.class,
                            () -> new FunctionRegistration<>(containsCloud())
                                    .type(FunctionType.from(String.class).to(Boolean.class)));
            
                    context.registerBean("uppercase", FunctionRegistration.class,
                            () -> new FunctionRegistration<>(uppercase()).type(FunctionType.from(String.class).to(String.class)));
                    context.registerBean("lowercase", FunctionRegistration.class,
                            () -> new FunctionRegistration<>(lowercase()).type(FunctionType.from(String.class).to(String.class)));
                    context.registerBean("getLength", FunctionRegistration.class,
                            () -> new FunctionRegistration<>(AnotherDemoFunction.getLength())
                                    .type(FunctionType.from(String.class).to(String.class)));
                    context.registerBean("getSquare", FunctionRegistration.class,
                            () -> new FunctionRegistration<>(DemoFunction.getSquare())
                                    .type(FunctionType.from(Integer.class).to(Double.class)));
                }
            }
```

4. This runs fine in local, I am able to call all the functions separately eg. `localhost:8083/lowercase -d ":SFDLKLs is A "` and `localhost:8083/getSquare -d 2`
5. I tried running this on Lambda , but I get the exception `Failed to locate function. Tried locating default function, function by '_HANDLER' env variable as well as'spring.cloud.function.definition`. I used the same handler function as before. Additionally provided the environment variable `spring_cloud_function_definition` with one of the function names as value
6. I tried also by changing the handler function to `org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker::handleRequest`. However it gives the exception of missing FunctionCatalog

Below are my dependencies and build plugin. `spring-boot-starter-parent` version is 2.5.4

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Required only during build phase for spring tests to pass and local run-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-function-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Basic Spring Cloud Function dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- AWS Specific dependency for deployment in Lambda -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Required for reading the AWS Lambda Request/Response event in Proxy 
            Mode -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Created Shaded and Thin jars -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.27.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>aws</shadedClassifierName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Is there any other way to have multiple Functions in Spring Cloud Functional Bean Definition for AWS Lambda

Comment: Why are you splitting s-c-function dependencies? Some are 3.1.3 and others 3.1.2.  There were some significant fixes for AWS IN 3.1.3 hence my question. Also, look at this sample as a good starting point - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/main/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-functional-sample-aws and let us know if you still have issues

Comment: Thanks @OlegZhurakousky , that worked just fine. I updated the dependencies to latest and emptied the main method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of Oleg's Comment I was able to achieve multiple functions with Functional Bean definition on AWS Lambda.

The changes done were as below

1. Emptied the main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            //FunctionalSpringApplication.run(Multi_FunctionalBean1Application.class, args);
    
}
```

2. Removed the function-webflux dependency and added function-web. Upgraded all spring cloud function dependencies to 3.2.0-SNAPSHOT. Updated pom below

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <wrapper.version>1.0.27.RELEASE</wrapper.version>
        <aws-lambda-events.version>3.9.0</aws-lambda-events.version>
        <spring-cloud-function.version>3.2.0-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud-function.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- AWS Specific dependency for deployment in Lambda -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Required for reading the AWS Lambda Request/Response event in Proxy 
            Mode -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20210307</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-function.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <!-- Created Shaded and Thin jars -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                        <version>${wrapper.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>aws</shadedClassifierName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

3. Changed the handler function in AWS Lambda to

> org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker::handleRequest

4. For running any specific function , used the Environment Variable `spring_cloud_function_definition` with function name as the value or a composition like func1|func2|func3

Comment: Also, if you setup API Gateway to that function, then you can pass `spring.cloud.function.definition` as an HTTP header, this making it more dynamic. There is also example for that . . . look for `routing` in aws samples

Answer (score 1):

With help from this thread, I was able to execute multiple Function(s) in AWS Lambda infrastructure using "spring_cloud_function_definition" environment variable. Thank you @Mayank for doing the research.

Couple of observations:

SpringAwsCloudFunctionApplication.java - observe that in the latest spring-boot (v3.1.0) the bean registration syntax has changed as follows.

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class SpringAwsCloudFunctionApplication implements ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FunctionalSpringApplication.run(SpringAwsCloudFunctionApplication.class, args);
    }

    public Function<String, String> reverseStringWithUpper() {
        return value -> new StringBuilder(value).reverse().toString().toUpperCase() + System.lineSeparator();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext context) {
        context.registerBean("reverseString",
                FunctionRegistration.class,
                () -> new FunctionRegistration<>(new ReverseStringFunction()).type(ReverseStringFunction.class));

        context.registerBean("reverseStringWithUpper",
                FunctionRegistration.class,
                () -> new FunctionRegistration<>(reverseStringWithUpper())
                        .type(FunctionTypeUtils.functionType(String.class, String.class)));

    }
```

ReverseStringFunction.java

```
@Component
public class ReverseStringFunction implements Function<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String apply(String input) {
        return new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString() + System.lineSeparator();
    }
}
```

Configuration screenshots in latest AWS-Lambda console

Handler configuration
[image: Handler configuration]

Function entry point (method to invoke) configuration
[image: Function entry point (method to invoke) configuration]

With this I am able to test the cloud functions locally (mvn spring-boot:run) and also on AWS.